# How to divide an array in to two different arrays in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an Array of Hash, and I need to divide it into two different arrays. The array of Hash looks like this:

```
 old_array = [
   {
      'a'=>1,
      'b'=>2,
      'c'=>3,
      'd'=>4
   },
   {  
      'e'=>5,
      'f'=>6,
      'g'=>7,
      'h'=>8
   },
  {  
      'i'=>9,
      'j'=>10,
      'k'=>11,
      'l'=>12
   },
  {  
      'm'=>13,
      'n'=>14,
      'o'=>15,
      'p'=>16
   }

];
```

I need to divide it into two different arrays in the manner:

```
   new_array_1 = [{
      'a'=>1,
      'b'=>2,
      'c'=>3,
      'd'=>4
   },
   {  
      'e'=>5,
      'f'=>6,
      'g'=>7,
      'h'=>8
   }
 ];


 new_array_2 = [{  
      'i'=>9,
      'j'=>10,
      'k'=>11,
      'l'=>12
   },
  {  
      'm'=>13,
      'n'=>14,
      'o'=>15,
      'p'=>16
   }
 ];
```

I have now tried the below code as mentioned in one of the answers:

```
     my ($new_array_1, $new_array_2) =
    map { [ $_ ] }
          @$old_array;
```

This is splitting the array but removing the middle hashes and, I am getting output as:

```
   $VAR1 = [
      {
        'c' => 3,
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 2,
        'd' => 4
      }
    ];

$VAR1 = [
      {
        'g' => 7,
        'f' => 6,
        'e' => 5,
        'h' => 8
      }
    ];
```

What shall I do to get the desired output? The hashes may increase to 10 or 20 or 15, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The question has changed significantly, where now the arrayref has not two elements but more, and it need be split so that its halves go into two arrays. Elements need not be made arrayrefs.*

Now one has to go to indices. (Well, or to alternate between new arrays while moving/copying element by element.) One way

```
my $midind = ($#$old_arrayref-1)/2;  # or: (@$oldarrayref/2)-1

my $new_arrayref_1 = [ @$old_arrayref[0..$midind] ];
my $new_arrayref_2 = [ @$old_arrayref[$midind+1 .. $#$old_array] ];
```

This preserves the original array as it was.  (The syntax `$#$arrayref` is for the last index in the arrayref `$arrayref`.) If the old array doesn't matter, can do instead

```
my $new_arrayref_1 = [ splice @$old_arrayref, 0, $midind+1 ];
my $new_arrayref_2 = [ @$old_arrayref ];
```

**NOTE**  If elements of the original array themselves contain complex data structures (so, references) then they need be "deep-copied," for example using `Storable::dclone`.

I still recommend working through resources linked in the original post (below), to learn how to work with arrays in this language.

---

*The original answer.  The question before it was changed had the initial array(ref) with strictly two elements, and once th  ey are split into two arrays they (seemingly) needed to be wrapped into arrayrefs.  This should still be useful for the list of basic resources (if the reader needs that).*

There is a range of operations supported on arrays in Perl. As for basics, we can remove and return an element from front or back, with [shift](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift) or `pop`, and can add with `unshift` or `push`.

Then there is more, including `splice` you tried, and then there are libraries for more complex operations. But the basics readily solve your quest.  One way

```
my $old_arrayref = [ { a=>1, b=>2 }, { c=>3, d=>4 } ];

my @new_array_1 = shift @$old_array;
my @new_array_2 = shift @$old_array;
```

(An [array](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro#Arrays) can be simply assigned a list of elements, including just one. But if there is anything in the array then that would be all gone after such an assignment so don't forget that.)

Here I take the source (`old_array`) to be an array-reference, following the question. Now that `$old_array` is empty, if it had only those two elements, which are now in `@new_array_N`'s. <sup>†</sup>

Another, even more elemental way, is to [index into the array](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Subscripts) to access individual elements and copy them to new arrays.  This way `$old_array` would stay as it is.

Perhaps a more reasonable arrangement is to have references for these two new arrays as elements of an array, which may be what your code attempts to do. For that you only need <sup>†</sup>

```
my @new_array = map { [ $_ ] } @$old_array;
```

The [map](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map) applies the code in the block to each element of its input (`@$old_array`), returning a list, assigned to `@new_array`. That `[]` in the body constructs an [anonymous array (reference)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut#Make-Rule-2), which is a scalar and as such can be placed on an array. The only element placed in this array-reference is the currently processed element of `@$old_array`, available in the (ubiquitous) [`$_` variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$_).

See `perlintro` and `perldata` linked above, and links in `shift`.  For many additional operations on lists and arrays, provided in libraries, see [List::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/List::Util) and [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) for starters.

For references see [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut) and for arrays with references see [perllol](https://perldoc.perl.org/perllol) (lists-of-lists) and [perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc) (data structures cookbook).

A complete program<sup>†</sup>

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dumper;

my @old_array = ( { 'a'=>1, 'b'=>2 }, { 'c'=>3, 'd'=>4 } );  

my @new_array = map { [ $_ ] } @old_array;

say Dumper \@new_array;
```

This prints (just condensed, for readability in this post)

```
$VAR1 = [
          [ { 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2 } ],
          [ { 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4 } ]
        ];
```

---

<sup>†</sup>  If the new array(s) need be array-references as well

```
my $new_arrayref_1 = [ shift @$old_array ];
my $new_arrayref_2 = [ shift @$old_array ];
```

In the second example, and in the short "complete program"

```
my $new_arrayref = [ map { [ $_ ] } @$old_array ];
```

Comment: Actually, with this logic, the array is not splitting into two.

Comment: @KamakshiTrivedi Can you add the code you have to your question?  (And clarify what exact output you expect -- one array with two array-references in it, or two separate arrays.) The little code snippets that I posted here work fine. I am adding a complete program, for copy-paste...

Comment: @KamakshiTrivedi I think I see what your problem is --  you have an array _reference_ to start with, not an array.  That's a very small adjustment to make, and I've adjusted the post to that.

Comment: (I meant that that was a problem you had _with this answer_.  Otherwise it's not a problem in any sense, having an array reference and not an array.)

Comment: I have edited the question, you can have a look at it.

Comment: @KamakshiTrivedi  That changes the question a lot.  I added one solution to the top of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You basically had the right answer. You originally had

```perl
my @new_array;
push @new_array, [ splice @$missingSections, 0, 2 ] while @$old_array;
```

It should have been

```perl
my @new_array;
push @new_array, [ splice @$old_array, 0, 2 ] while @$old_array;
```

This could also be written as follows:

```perl
use List::MoreUtils qw( natatime );

my @new_array;
my $iter = natatime 2, @$old_array;
while ( my @vals = $iter->() ) {
   push @new_array, \@vals;
}
```

```perl
my @new_array =
   map [ $old_array->@[ $_*2+0, $_*2+1 ] ],
      0..@$old_array/2;
```

```perl
use List::Util qw( pairs );

my @new_array = pairs @$old_array;
```

```perl
use List::MoreUtils qw( part );

my @new_array = part { $_/2 } 0..$#$old_array;
```